# How to convert/cast column data type in concatenated SQL query string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

i have the following variables defined in my stored procedure

```
@StartDate  DateTime,
@EndDate    DateTime,
```

I'm setting the sql to be executed dynamically, so when constructing the query where clause i have the below line.

```
SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (convert(datetime, R.ReportDate, 121) >= ' + @StartDate + 'AND  convert(datetime, R.ReportDate, 121) <=' + @EndDate +')'
```

When i execute the stored procedure, the line above throws the error below

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

If i change the variable datatype to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, the procedure executes successfully but then returns no rows because the date comparison/matching fails.

ReportDate column is of datatype datetime and has data in this format `2014-06-01 00:00:00.000`

As you can see i have tried converting the column when constructing my query but that isn't working.

Comment: A `DATETIME` column in SQL Server *has NO format!* - it's an 8-byte binary datatype. So I don't understand why you're using `CONVERT` to a `DateTime` on a column that **already IS** a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` is a `DateTime` is a `DateTime` - no need to do any string "formatting" on it ! Just use it natively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with `ReportDate`, but when you are trying to concatenate your DateTime parameters with your nvarchar sql statement. The problem can be reproduced fairly simply with:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Some text' + GETDATE();
```

The wrong way to fix this is to convert the datetime parameter to a string so that it can be concatenated with a string, e.g.

```
SET @sql = @sql + ' AND r.ReportDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' 
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @StartDate, 112) 
                + ''', 112) AND r.ReportDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' +
                + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @EndDate, 112) 
                + ''', 112)';
```

<sup>N.B. I am including this for completeness of the answer, and in no way endorse this approach</sup>

The correct way to fix this is to use [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188001(v=sql.90).aspx) and pass properly typed parameters this way, this will avoid conversion issues. e.g.

```
SET @sql = @sql + 'AND r.ReportDate >= @StartDateParam AND r.ReportDate <= @EndDateParam';

EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @sql, 
    N'@StartDateParam DATETIME, @EndDateParam DATETIME',
    @StartDateParam = @StartDate,
    @EndDateParam = @EndDate
```